# Java : How to handle file size exceed exception of tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, exception, multipart

I am working on spring boot project in which I want to handle maximum file size exceed exception (I want to upload only those file which has size less than 10MB and if anyone try to upload file greater than 10 MB it should return a message not a exception) , after searching on internet I have tried all the possible solutions but nothing worked

Anyone can tell me about this ?

**FileUploadController.class**

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Controller
public class FileUploadController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{
@ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/uploadChildPhoto/{childId}", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> uploadChildPhoto(Authentication authentication,
            @PathVariable("childId") Long childId, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,MaxUploadSizeExceededException exc) {
        try {
            if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                ChildPhoto createdPhoto = childService.createChildPhoto(file, childId);
                return ResponseEntity.ok(createdPhoto);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "You failed to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " because the file was empty");
            }
        } catch (MultipartException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).body("File size error");
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (14816520) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:805) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2864) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3211) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1137) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:75) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
```

**MaximumFileSize**

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Comment: looks like the file size is around 14 MB, shouldn't you try bumping up your config value to a higher one and try?

Comment: @Chids Yes ! file size is 14MB and I want to limit the file size 10MB .. and if anyone uploads file greater than 10MB than it shows message not stuck on exception

Comment: This exceptions get thrown before your code - it is in Tomcat

Comment: @ScaryWombat then how I can handle this ?

Answer (score 3):

Since tomcat is throwing the exception you are not able to handle it. Thus you need to tell tomcat to allow all size of files to be uploaded and handle the size at controller level.

set multipart properties below 
multipart: max-file-size: -1 max-request-size: -1

set Tomcat 8 (maxSwallowSize="-1")
on controller, add logic to check size

```
if(fileAttachment.getSize() > 10485760 ) { throw new MaxUploadSizeExceededException(fileAttachment.getSize()); }
```

Comment: a useful link https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-file-upload-and-connection-reset-issue/

Comment: You can *absolutely* handle this in your own code: use a `Filter` and catch the exception, then respond however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this - spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB control is not going to controller. Tomcat only throwing exception.
If you want to return message then remove these lines from properties file and add a check in your controller only like:

```
 if (file.getSize() > 10000000){
  throw new RuntimeException("File size error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned exception thrown from tomcat .it couldn't reach out to the controller.

So,there are many possible ways we can handle this (:

**1.Add the below application property and do the size restriction logic.**

> spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=-1

> spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=-1

the **-1** indicates it can allow unlimited size. But this is ok for development not for production grade application.

inside the logic class you can define your size limit logic. You can get the size of the file and throw a expection as you desired.

```
    if(fileAttachment.getSize() > 10485760 ) 
  {
//error logic throwing exception or return the error response.
 }
```

note : 10485760  byte value equals to 10MB

2.Mentioning a multipart exception in a generalException handler class.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
        @ExceptionHandler(MultipartException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String>fileExced(MultipartException ex){
    return ResponseEntity.ok("File limit exceeded..!");
}
```

This sizeExceedException mentioned in the question is implicitly invoke the multipart exception.so whenever the file limit exceeds the above error message will throws.